# Перенос переменной при выводе в консоль

Tags: python

подскажите как на переносимой строке отображать переменную?

пробовал так:

```
msg = "1я"
print("Внимание программа продолжаться не будет\nобнаружена ошибка, текст ошибки:" +  \n + msg)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если я правильно понял

способ 1:

```
print("текст", msg, sep='\n')
```

способ 2:

```
print(f"текст\n{msg}")
```

способ 3:

```
print("текст")
print(msg)
```

если я понял не правильно - то используйте способ 2 и вставляйте переменную туда, куда вам хочется

Comment: вы поняли все верно)